# Statistical Probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

The Canadian Tobacco Monitoring Survey is a national survey administered by Statistics Canada to study smoking trends of Canadians aged $15$ or older. The most recent survey found that $19$% of Canadians aged $15$ years or older smoke on a daily basis. In addition, $22$% of men are smokers, and $16$% of women are smokers.

The most recent census shows that men make up $50$% of the Canadian population, with women making up the remainder.

You randomly pick a Canadian that is $15$ years old or older. What is the probability this person

a) Is male and a smoker?

b) is a women and not a smoker?

c) What percentage of smokers are male?

d) What percentage of smokers are women?

I think I've got $1/2$ of a probability table figured out,

P(Male) = $0.5$

P(Male complement) = $0.5$,

P(Smoker) = $0.19$

P(Smoker Complement) = $0.81$

I'm just stuck on how to fill in the middle. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the answer for part (a)?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm not sure. I know that it involves the fact that $22%$ of men are smokers. But I don't know the exact calculation. I tried multiplying $0.22$ by $0.5$ but this was not correct.

Comment: Are you saying that $0.11$ or $11\%$ is incorrect?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I must have done the calculation wrong. I was correct. thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you get for part (b)?

Comment: 0.42 @N.F.Taussig

Comment: That is also correct.  Do you understand part (c)?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate it. I originally thought it was P(Smoker given Male) But i dont think this is the right answer. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: P(A)=P(being_smoker),P(B)=P(being_male), thus $P(A \cap B)=P(A|B)*P(B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the probability that a Canadian who is at least $15$ years old is male and a smoker?

Let $M$ denote the set of males; let $S$ denote the set of smokers.  Then the probability we seek is 
$$P(M \cap S) = P(S \mid M)P(M) = 0.22 \cdot 0.5 = 0.11$$
as you found.

> What is the probability that a Canadian who is at least $15$ years old is female and a non-smoker?

Let $F$ denote the set of females; let $S$ denote the set of smokers.  Then the probability we seek is 
$$P(F \cap S^C) = P(S^C \mid F)P(F) = (1 - 0.16)(0.5) = 0.84 \cdot 0.5 = 0.42$$
again as you found.

> What percentage of smokers are male?

We need to find the probability that a person is male given that the person is a smoker.
\begin{align*}
P(S \mid M) & = \frac{P(M \cap S)}{P(S)}\\
            & = \frac{P(M \cap S)}{P(M \cap S) + P(F \cap S)}\\
            & = \frac{P(S \mid M)P(M)}{P(S \mid M)P(M) + P(F \mid M)P(F)}\\
            & = \frac{0.22 \cdot 0.5}{0.22 \cdot 0.5 + 0.16 \cdot 0.5}\\
            & = \frac{0.11}{0.11 + 0.08}\\
            & = \frac{0.11}{0.19}\\
            & = \frac{11}{19}
\end{align*}
which you can convert into a percentage.

> What percentage of smokers are women?

Subtract the percentage of smokers who are male from $100\%$.

Comment: Thank you good sir, for all the help.